# Преобразование структуры в байты и обратно

Tags: c++

```
struct ST_M_Message 
{
    LongWord num_pack;          //4 Номер пакета
    LongWord id;                //4 Идентификатор
    byte data_len;              //1 Длина сообщения
    byte data[8];               //8 Данные
};
```

Пытаюсь преобразовать нулевой указатель в байты и обратно

```
ST_M_Message first;
ST_M_Message second;
int size = sizeof(ST_M_Message);

// указатель на исходная структура
void* nptr = &first;
// пытаюсь сделать из исходного байты
uint8_t* buf = static_cast<uint8_t*>(nptr);
// и собрать обратно во вторую структуру
memcpy(&second, &buf , size);
```

И данные в получившемся second абсолютно не те.

```
// примерный вид в моем коде
// отправляю first в функцию отправки
sent($first, sizeof(ST_M_Message ))

void sent(void* data, size_t size)
{
    uint8_t* buf = static_cast<uint8_t*>(data);
    byte buf[25];
    // Первые 8 байт - хедер
    buf[0] = 1;  // тип телеграммы
    buf[1] = 0;
    buf[2] = 0;
    buf[3] = 0;
    buf[4] = 0;
    buf[5] = 0;
    buf[6] = 0;
    buf[7] = 0;

    memcpy(&buf[AV_PACKAGE_HEADER_SIZE], &data, size);
    // на этом этапе в buf не те данные, где я ошибся?
    sendto(FSocket, (char*)&buf, sizeof(buf) , 0, (SOCKADDR*)&FSAddr, sizeof(FSAddr));
}

потом при приеме пытаюсь собрать структуру
ST_M_Message second;
memcpy(&second, &buf, size);
```

Comment: не понятно, что ты делаешь и что не так…

Comment: Изменил, может так понятнее будет

Comment: `&buf` - лишнее взятие адреса. Вся эта конструкция записывается как `::std::memcpy(::std::addressof(second), ::std::addressof(first), size);` А `size` должна иметь тип `::std::size_t`, а не `int`.

Comment: @user7860670 А зачем в структуре, в которой оператор `&` не переопределен, `addressof`?

Comment: Я таки не понял... Вы что, хотите передать значение *указателя*?!

Comment: Данные. в first условно есть id = 123, когда я кастую данные в second  id уже -12 (или любой другой мусор туда записывается)

Comment: @Mikhailo `addressof` показывает, что в тут требуется обращение непосредственно к байтам объекта.

Comment: @user7860670 Показывает пользователю или компилятору? В смысле, что `memcpy(&second, &first , size);` будет неверным?

Answer (score 3):

Ну а зачем брать не указатель, а его адрес?!!

```
memcpy(&second, &buf , size);
```

Попробуйте

```
memcpy(&second, buf , size);
```

А еще проще —

```
memcpy(&second, &first , size);
```

А так — вы просто копируете в `second` значение лежащего в `buf` адреса + неизвестную память рядом с этой переменной.

Comment: Суть в том, что void* передается в функцию и в ней преобразуется в байты отправляется через sentto, и в другом месте "декодируется". Просто упростил этапы